# SOAP replacements/workarounds/libraries in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Being as stubborn as it gets, I'm building my own PHP-based CMS and framework (named RAmen/[FSM](http://venganza.org) just for the kicks) that has been deployed multiple times for my customers. Now, I'm going to develop a support ticket application for it that I will deploy on a 'central' server for convenience of maintenance.

Now, I've looked into SOAP services and was happy until I got to WSDL generation in PHP and in itself. So, what would you suggest for me to 'securely' (as in, no https) manage this with SOAP-like simplicity on the client side (`$support->newTicket`), without the WSDL headaches on the server side? Or should I –gasp– stop being so stubborn and just go with a PHP library (in which case, please do recommend!)

Thank you, fellow pastafarians/spagnostic coders!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a [native SOAP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php), that automates client as well as server. It is a little buggy in some places, but still better than nusoap (IMHO).

That said, I would never chose SOAP if I had any bearing on the decision. Use xml-rpc or a rest-based approach.

Comment: I think that's subjective. xml-rpc is an old and well-established standard, with a lot of support, including stable, tried-and-tested implementations for a host of platforms.

Comment: Yes, this is probably closer to what I'm looking for. Could you point our some resources for getting the hang of XML-RPC apart from php.net?

Thanks!

Comment: The manual has a [whole section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php) on using it.

Comment: Thanks! I read the manual pages all over again, and it actually made sense this time. Going with JSON responses on a REST approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar question, whether to use REST or SOAP.  I am using REST but that is beacuse i want a simple API like function not so much the rigid functionality associated with REST.

That being said here is a nice little library to get you started on SOAP

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

By the sounds of it SOAP is actually what you want.  you will fin it a bit easier to implement as you get the domain models from the WSDL.

Comment: Not meaning to sound excessively picky, but, the last relase of NuSOAP was on 2007, and PHP has grown since. Could you elaborate a bit more on your REST workflow?